# OK button click in [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] No mail accounts alert message

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

My goal is - try to send an e-mail from my application (recipient, subject, body and attachment filled from an app), and if no mail accounts present, show `UIActivityViewController` to the user for upload attachment file to any other app, which can handle that.

All is fine, but when  `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] == NO`
user faces with system alert with "No mail accounts" text. AND under that message - mentioned `UIActivityViewController`.

How to catch "OK" - button click in system alert to show `UIActivityViewController` only after system alert dismissed?

Comment: I think you are trying to send e-mail. so why not trying [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]

Comment: omg. I've been mistaken with two VERY similar controllers:
`MFMailComposeViewController`
vs
`MFMessageComposeViewController`
Thanks!

Comment: Your most welcome.